# derby.stream.error.rollingFile.limit property in Derby.properties is not working as rollover is not working as expected

Tags: derby

Need help on the below configuration not reflecting in derby.properties.
Kindly have a look on this and see if you can help us on resolving/shed light on this.

"derby.stream.error.rollingFile.limit=5120000 " in derby.properties doesn't perform rotation even after 5MB file size is reached.It keeps growing as much as it can.

But other parameters like "derby.infolog.append=true " is getting reflected as i could derby.log getting appended instead of new log creation.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling log is implemented in version 10.11.1.1 and above. https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi

You are most likely using an older version.